# Single-node Hadoop namenode format fails on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, hadoop, command

I'm trying to start a single-node Hadoop cluster on Mac OS X (Mavericks). When I get to this step:

`$ bin/hadoop namenode -format`

I get this error:

`bin/hadoop: line 391: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Line 391 (which is the very last line) of bin/hadoop has a terminating "fi" on it, that's all.

Is there something different about running this on Mac OS X that I'm missing? Other answers to similar problems seem to point to having the "wrong" newline as a possible cause, but I don't really understand these answers as they pertain to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the file hadoop.sh had been edited and saved with an editor that had probably introduced some end-of-line characters unacceptable to bash. After getting a fresh install and editing with vi, all went well.